# How to hightlight a word in Js

Tags: javascript, html

How can I highlight the word

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zp6078h/)

Code:

```
AutoSuggestControl.prototype.selectRange = function (iStart /*:int*/, iLength /*:int*/) {
    //use text ranges for Internet Explorer
    debugger
    var range = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);

    var oRange = selection;
    oRange.moveStart("character", iStart);
    oRange.moveEnd("character", iLength);
    oRange.select();


    //set focus back to the textbox
    this.textbox.focus();
};
```

but it shows error in `moveEnd` and `moveStart` function

Comment: Please provide HTML DOM with the script or fiddle snippet to understand where to highlight

Comment: oRange is a Selection, not a Fragment. Maybe you wanted to say `var oRange = range` instead of `var oRange = selection`? However, the methods `moveStart` and `moveEnd` are defined for neither [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) nor [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), (except in IE). Maybe you meant [`Range.prototype.setStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart)?

Comment: I want to select from `iStart` to `iLength` in text..and selection does not have moveStart method..I dont know more about it..so tried it.. @RaphaelSchweikert

Comment: So I guess you need to edit the Range before adding it to the selection using `addRange`. Also the `TextRange` type on which IE has a `moveStart` and `moveEnd` method is not the same as a DOM `Range` type. Use `range.setStart(domNode, iStart)` and `setEnd(domNode, iStart+iLength)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple function

```
 function hilighter(word, element) {
        var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
        var repl = '<span class="HiLighterClass">' + word + '</span>';
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
    }
```

**Use**

you can get element by in different way, like by Id, Class etc

```
hilighter('youWord', document.getElementByTag("Body"));
```